# Meaning of "graced their sight with its presence"

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, learning

What is the meaning of "graced their sight with its presence" in below sentence?

One night when they stood at their respective balconies looking skyward at the starry night, a shooting star graced their sight with its presence.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIhQCow8CIo

Start at 3:27

Answer (score 1):

It's flowery language, anthromorphising a meteor by suggesting that (like a royal personage appearing before the crowds) its appearance is graciously granting its viewers a view (with a little wave) before returning back into its private seclusion once more.